# phonegap openDatabase no method

Tags: javascript, android, html, sql, cordova

I am developing a phonegap app that requires a database.

On a few pages it handles the database, but on the initial running of the app it fills the database. The code works fine on android version 2.X.X, however fails on android version 4.X.X

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Database", 500000);
```

Whilst I have read up that there can be issues with the openDatabase function, but in my app it DOES work on a few pages, just not this one! It's always this line that fails.

The logCat output for this page says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'openDatabase' at file
```

As I say, it works on other pages, but not this one. I've tried rewriting it making sure it works in the same way as the other page, even written an entirely new page to handle it, but in the end it always comes down to that one line which is exactly the same.

and yes, phonegaps javascript is imported.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the solution that worked for me is to use openDatabase in the "deviceReady" event handler.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "DBNAME", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}
```